# Google+ iOS SDK - Get the list of people who follow "me"

Tags: ios, iphone, google-plus

I'm using Google+ iOS SDK to integrate with my app and I would like to know if there is a way to query what people have me in their circles (that is, the people who follow me) or if I can somehow retrieve that information from the people feed that I obtain with the following:

```
GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleListWithUserId:@"me" collection:kGTLPlusCollectionPublic];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That info isn't available. The only supported `collections` for [people.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list) are `connected` and `visible`, both of which are based on people in the authenticated users circles.

There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=529) that I think covers such an API method.